# Android Time Picker Dialog

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am trying to make a time picker dialog. I followed [this android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). I want to show the dialog when the user clicks a button. When I click the button, **I get this error "requestFeature() must be called before adding content".**

Here is my Time Picker Fragment Code:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public TimePickerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_picker, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, hour, minute, false);
    return dialog;
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // do something with user's input
    }
};
```

My button is in another activity and its xml "onclick" attribute calls this method:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View view) {
    DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
    timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

**Android is telling me to add requestFeature() somewhere. I don't understand where to put this code and which feature to request.**

EDIT:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
        at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
        at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:361)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:262)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:490)
        at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1724)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:918)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? somewhere in the code you're requesting a window feature(perhaps full screen, or no title?) *after* setting the contentview. These requests need to be made *before* setting the content view

Comment: I have posted it as an edit. I can't find requestFeature() anywhere in my project.

Comment: where is the code for your main activity? check to see if you have the method requestFeature() anyehere in your main activitie's onCreate() method. if so put that method before the onCreate method.

Comment: Can you add the source to your OnFragmentInteractionListener.onFragmentInteraction() code please?

Comment: @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
This method is empty.

Comment: @LairdPleng 
I figured it out. The problem was caused by implementing both onCreateDialog() and onCreateView(). I only need inCreateDialog(). Thank you.

Comment: glad you sussed it out. You should write and accept an answer in case anybody else comes across the problem :)